# question about power set unions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is P(A) ∪ P(B) = P(A ∪ B) true for all sets A and B? If so, prove it. If not, give an example of sets A and B for which it is false.

So we can suppose that X ∈ P(A) ∨ P(A). Therefore X ∈ P(A) ∨ X ∈ P(B). Then we can say X ⊆ A ∨ X ⊆ B. Then X ⊆ (A ∨ B), so X ∈ P(A∨B).

So P(A) ∪ P(B) = P(A ∪ B) for any set A and B.

Is that correct? It'd be great if someone could confirm this for me, thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to write "So we can suppose that $X \in P(A) \vee P(\color{red}{B})$?

Comment: yes, my mistake.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

**Counterexample.**  $A = \{1\}$, $B = \{2\}$.
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{P}(A) & = \{\emptyset, \{1\}\}\\
\mathcal{P}(B) & = \{\emptyset, \{2\}\}\\
\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B) & = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}\}\\
\mathcal{P}(A \cup B) & = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}\}
\end{align*}

While $P(A) \cup P(B) \subseteq P(A \cup B)$, the reverse inclusion is not true in general.

Comment: oh ok I see now, I had written down the powersets and I thought that {1,2} made sense because it wasnt in either A or B. thanks a lot, I understand it  now. so my answer could be "if P(A)∪P(B)⊆P(A∪B) is true then P(A∪B) ⊆ P(A) or P(B) must be true, but we can see if A ={1} and B = {2} that {1,2} is a subset of P(A∪B) that is not present in either P(A) or P(B)?"

Comment: Compare $\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)$ with $\mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$.  Only the latter contains $A \cup B = \{1, 2\}$.  Therefore, $\mathcal{P}(A \cup B) \not\subseteq \mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not correct: you've only shown that the union of the powersets is contained in the powerset of the unions. Try to prove the converse. Suppose $X\in \mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$: now what? If $X\cap A \ne \emptyset$ and $X\cap B \ne \emptyset$, then $X\notin \mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)$.